# Get checkbox "checked" state based on MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an article field that has tags associated with each record. When a user is editing an article, how do I display the tags in a checkbox list, preselected for those that apply?

The checkbox I've tried to use so far:

```
Tetradic Color<input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_POST[articletags_78])) echo 'checked="checked" ' ?>name="articletags[]" value="checkbox" id="articletags_78" />
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish Your first comment was correct, I'm trying to find out how to display a preselected checkbox list. As for the rest of your comment, I've been under the impression thus far that it's important to provide context instead of just the code itself, especially as the fact that I'm really new at this means that I could have inserted an error somewhere else in the code, rather than directly where I'm working. I apologize for creating too much work for you.

Comment: Alright, I'm deleting the comments, I'm sure you get the point. When the article is created, is the creator/author typing in a list of words as tags? And then they can toggle checkboxes after the fact? Why does the mode of interaction change so much? Can they type in new tags on the edit screen in a textbox?

Comment: There are 2 modes of input: 1st there are 4 text fields and then there are the checkboxes. The reason I went with checkboxes is to enforce consistency in the spelling of tags across users and so that the user doesn't have to already know what the tags are. The method that Stackoverflow uses, for example, is really cool but it means that the user has to know "MySQL" instead of "My SQL" or something like that. The tags aren't intended to be editable.

Comment: For context, the database will be used primarily by undergraduate interns that are unfamiliar with the material, but who will be inputting information into the database. (which is why consistency was one of my concerns)

Comment: I'm working on putting together a demo on my site using the code you initially posted as a starting point. Give me 30 minutes or so though.

Comment: Wow, thanks! No worries, I'm still hacking away at it myself.

Comment: Also, did you consider using a framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.org) or a CMS like [Drupal](http://drupal.org) to build your system with? The way you're embedding your presentation layer (HTML) within your functions as an entire HTML document is a real problem. You might also look at [Fuel CMS](http://www.getfuelcms.com/) or [concrete5 CMS](http://www.concrete5.org/about/editors-tour/).

Comment: Actually, the ITCS dept of the people I've been working with were supposed to supply me with a set of Cold Fusion template forms but they never did. And I tried for a week to get permission to install and use a Wordpress site, but the beuracracy has kept bouncing me from team to team. (to their credit, they are in the midst of a Sharepoint upgrade and are too busy to be bothered with me)

Comment: Ahh, the Sharepoint fugue state, AKA the Zombie! Bop. They want FUD, FUUUD! Alright, well, I think you could still run a CodeIgniter site through a folder on a server or whatnot without needing any more special rights, if you're really interested. It actually does give you quite a bit of tools to work with, including a way to create templates in a sane way. [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/install) literally just installs into a folder. Some of the "lighter" frameworks install with few restrictions nowadays.

Comment: I would have loved to know that a month ago most definitely. Will look into using Slim especially if I'm stricken with future projects such as this. (I'm not in the computer science department, I'm an English major!)

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer for sure. Sorry it's taking me so long; I've been multi-tasking a bit with work-related stuff.

Comment: How do you `SELECT` your `TAG_CONTENTS` from the table?

Comment: As of right now I don't. I've only just gotten the whole thing working where I can make associations between ARTICLES and TAGS by using the ID of the newest INSERT INTO ARTICLES and the ID of the TAG passed by the checkbox. So, so far, I haven't worked with TAG_CONTENTS at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12832/discussion-between-jared-farrish-and-newlymintedcocoaguy)

Answer (score 0):

change this for a start:

```
<p>Tetradic Color<input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_POST[articletags_78])) echo 'checked="checked" ' ?>name="articletags[]" value="checkbox" id="articletags_78" /></p>
```

to this:

```
<p>Tetradic Color<input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_POST["articletags_78"])) { echo 'checked="checked" '; } ?>name="articletags[]" value="checkbox" id="articletags_78" /></p>
```